# Gstreamer (-sharp)-- how to add my custom sink to splitmuxsink

Tags: c#, gstreamer, h.264, gstreamer-sharp

I want to add my custom sink for splitmuxsink, namely I want to split h264  stream from ip camera into chunks by 10 seconds, but I want it in some controlled by me buffer. Smth like pipeline below but instead of file, I want to handle appsink event "NewSample" and work with 10 second buffer on my own, not to store to file:

```
gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc buffer-mode=0  location=rtsp://camera?videocodec=h264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location="data_%02d.mp4" max-size-time=10000000000
```

So, I want to reproduce it in my C# code and use my custom sink instead of default one (filesink). In [docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/multifile/splitmuxsink.html?gi-language=c#properties) it is stated:

> By default, it uses mp4mux and filesink, but they can be changed via the 'muxer' and 'sink' properties.

Here is my code:

```
    var rtph264depay = ElementFactory.Make("rtph264depay", "rtph264depay");
    var h264parse = ElementFactory.Make("h264parse", "h264parse");
    var splitmuxsink = ElementFactory.Make("splitmuxsink", "splitmuxsink");
    splitmuxsink["max-size-time"] = 10000000000;
    splitmuxsink["async-finalize"] = false;

  
    var tempBin = splitmuxsink as Bin;

    var appSink = new AppSink("my_appsink");
    appSink.NewSample += AppSink_NewSample;
    appSink.EmitSignals = true;

    splitmuxsink["sink"] = appSink;
```

Code above gives a warn:

WARN                     bin gstbin.c:1391:gst_bin_add_func: Element 'my_appsink' already has parent

WARNING **: 18:57:08.508: Could not add sink elements - splitmuxsink will not work

Given that property Parent of appSink is null. Another approach I use:

```
 appSink.Parent = tempBin; //or tempBin.Add(appSink)
```

gives the very same error.

What I'm doing wrong? Is there another approach to handle h264 chunks manually in my buffer via splitmuxsink custom sink?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be the issue with code, which is not presented above, namely I added appSink as separate element to pipeline:

```
pipeline.Add(rtspsrc, rtph264depay ,h264parse, splitmuxsink,  appSink);
```

which is wrong, because appSink is already part of splitmuxsink. So everything seems to be working with:

```
    pipeline.Add(rtspsrc, rtph264depay ,h264parse, splitmuxsink ); //exclude appsink
```